# Does an Alchemist (or any class with the Bomb feature) with Breath Weapon Bomb qualify for feats affecting breath weapon attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, feat-qualifications

I plan to play a [Bomber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/flaming-crab-games---rogue-archetypes/bomber) (a Rogue who uses bombs instead of sneak attacks and has access to Alchemist discoveries that upgrade bombs) and by level 6 I plan to get [Breath Weapon Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/breath-weapon-bomb) to turn regular bombs into breath weapon attacks in a cone.

Then I saw some feats that improve breath weapons, like [this one](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/frog-god-games/monster-feats---3pp---frog-god-games/shape-breath-weapon). And I wonder if the Breath Weapon Bomb discovery is enough to qualify for this feat. If so, the [Strafe Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/strafe-bomb-su) discovery would likely become obsolete...

Comment: The Shape Breath Weapon feat is from a third-party publisher, and those kinds of feats are harder to adjudicate because they receive less developer and fan attention. (Not that I doubt the site's ability to do so, of course.) If there's a Paizo-published breath weapon-related feat that interests you, it'd be great if that were your example instead.

Comment: Interesting to note, even with Shape Breath Weapon Bomb, the result is  different than Strafe bomb. Strafe makes a 40ft line of splash damage (with 1 target taking full damage), while your feated up breath weapon will make a 30ft line that does x1.5 extra damage to one 1 target (and normal damage to others). So strafe (especially with explosive bomb) has longer range.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement for Shape Breath Weapon is "Breath weapon as a special attack." 'Special Attack' isn't well defined for non-npcs, however 'natural' breath weapons (from a dragon, gorgon, etc.) use the Universal Monster Rules 'Breath Weapon' entry, which specifies that they are supernatural abilities. The Bomber class says that it uses the Bomb class feature of the alchemist, which is also a supernatural ability.

Since both of these abilties are the same type, and that Breath Weapon Bomb specifies that it is being used as a breath weapon, I'd conclude that it is sufficient to satisfy the requirements of Shape Breathe Weapon.

Comment: I searched more feats that affect breat weapon attacks, but only one has for only prerequisite a breath weapon. All others have much more specific and hard to get prerequisites (like one requires a bite attack and an acidic breath weapon and another requires levels in the Dragon Disciple class).